# Problems with jQuery UI datepicker in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, datepicker

I've got a problem with jQuery UI datepicker it won't display correctly in chrome, all other browser it's displayed correctly. Im not quite sure when this started, because it worked when I first added it to the website.

And I tried a lot of CSS tweaks but nothing seems to work :O

This is the url http://jomfruanegade.dk/

Does anyone know what the problems is??

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can see the datepicker in the url that i've posted. And of course the css and html there

But sure I can post it if you like? :)

Comment: What css fix have you insert?

Comment: If you want help, you need to help us help you. And making us go look into a site's HTML/CSS is not helpful when you can post it in here.

Comment: What jQuery UI css version are you including? Normally it works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: left` from these two places:

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar > thead { ... }
table.ui-datepicker-calendar > thead th { ... }
```

Also remove the `height: 40px;` from:

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody td { ... }
```

Addition:

Add `verticle-align: bottom;` to:

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar > tbody td { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:D

Was exactly, what i needed.

The first row i tbody does still havea large margin to the bottom. How can I remove that? I have set margin: 0;

Comment: Yeah :) It's almost there. Is still creating a 5px bottom margin. Do you know why?

Comment: @AlexSleiborg learning to use Google Chrome Developer Tools and FireBug for FireFox to troubleshoot CSS issues will greatly help you troubleshooting these issues. I have added another fix for the first week being taller. Please accept the answer if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Rob.

First thanks for an incredible help:)

I am using Google Chrome Developer Tools. But these things like setting vertical-align: bottom; To remove 5px bottom margin, and remove a fixed height on a <td> so some margin disappears, seems really odd.